# Is a visa needed for Indian citizens who are U.S. permanent residents to enter Mexico?

Tags: visas, planning, india, mexico

My family is traveling by air to Mexico for a vacation (more specifically, Cancún). Since I was born in the U.S. and am thus a U.S. citizen, I can get into Mexico without advance arrangements. However, both my parents aren't U.S. citizens (they're Indian citizens and passport holders), but are U.S. permanent resident card holders.

- Do they need to make advance arrangements for a visa, or can they make do with the fact that they are U.S. permanent residents?
- If we are going to travel in ten days, is it too late to get visas at the moment (if they need one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**.  As US permanent residents, [your parents do not need visas](http://www.inm.gob.mx/index.php/page/Paises_Visa/en.html):

> A foreign who has any of the following documents **shall not require Mexican visa**:
>
> a) A document certifying permanent residence in Canada, **USA**, Japan, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, or any of the countries of the Schengen Area;

Comment: The link has changed and no longer goes to the quoted text.